# how to extract data from a link

Tags: bash, parsing, variables

I got a webpage source which I want to extract numbers from the links on the page. the first/last name are embedded in link. 
I manage to parse all links from the page, by saving the code first and then using cat and grep
I got the result in the form of

```
<a href="/apartments/rent/city-firstLastname.html">

cat webpage | grep apartments | \
while read line; do
echo ${line%.html}
done
```

how can I extract and echo the firstname, lastname from my while loop. I'm guessing my variable manipulation is missing something
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ${line} | sed 's/.*rent\/.*\-//' | sed 's/\.html.*//'
```

will give you `firstLastname` for each `<a…` line, but you'd need to provide more data to get any further.

`grep`, `sed`, etc were *never* meant to parse HTML files. Give [pup](https://github.com/EricChiang/pup) a try in your next project.

Answer (score 0):

this will echo just the firstlastname part, if you remove the cut you can keep the .html.  Also not that this is a big factor but cut is going to be much faster than sed, as it is much less complex.

cat webpage |  egrep -oi '[a-z]+.html"' | cut -d. -f1